# Matlab Simulink host scope file location

Tags: matlab, scope, simulink, host

I have a simulink model and I want to save data to my host computer. In Matlab help, host scope is suggested. However, Matlab does not ask a file name or save location when placing host scope into model. How can I access the data?
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

`Real-time Host Scope` blocks don't save their data to file, they save it into a property of the real-time object (used to start and stop the code execution amongst other things).

See [Real-Time Scope Objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/xpc/ug/target-scope-objects.html?searchHighlight=real-time%20scope%20object&s_tid=doc_srchtitle), for a discussion on how to get scope data and set scope properties.